# Ideal of formal power series over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, formal-power-series

I found this solution [Ideals of formal power series ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121354/ideals-of-formal-power-series-ring).

I can follow the proof, but I'm a bit confused on what $a$ is. It seems as if in the solution, to define $a$, we need to know what $I$ is first, but then we eventually used $a$ to define $I = (t^a)$. Isn't that a bit circular?

So for a concrete example, suppose our field is $\mathbb{R}$ and we want to find the ideals in $\mathbb{R}[[t]]$. How do we find our $a$ in this case?

Comment: Given $I$, $a$ as defined exists.  What's the problem?

Comment: isn't it that whole point of the problem is that we want to find the ideal $I$? We want to determine the ideals of the ring.

Comment: No, $I$ is already handed to you.  You want to prove that $I$ has an alternate expression as $(t^a)$.

Comment: So for example, if the field is $\mathbb{R}$, then what's our $I$?

Comment: There is no $I$.  There are MANY ideals.  The problem is trying to classify them.  "Let $I$ be any ideal in this ring.  Then $I=(t^a)$ for some $a$."

Comment: Did you see this in the link you gave?  *"Let $I$ be an ideal and $p\in I$..."*  The "let" tells you they are assuming you have an $I$ in your hands, but this $I$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Ok that just made a lot of sense. I think I finally get what it's saying now. thanks @Randall

Comment: The proofs obscure the simple idea: every element has form $\,ut^a\,$ for a unit $u$ so if $\,a\le $ all $a_i$ then $\large (u t^a, u_1 t^{a_1}, u_2 t^{a_2},\ldots) = (t^a, t^{a_1}, t^{a_2},\ldots) = t^a (\color{#c00}1, t^{a_1-a}, t^{a_2-a},\ldots) = t^a(\color{#c00}1) = (t^a)$ $\ \ \ $

Comment: More generally see DVRs = [discrete valuation rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring).